# Diffraction grating equation differentiation

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to calculate the change in diffraction angle with change of diffraction grating period. I have found papers giving appropriate equations, but I'd like to better understand maths behind this.
According to one of the papers if we start with simple grating equation (for first order only):
$$P\sin\beta=\pm\lambda$$
where P is spatial frequency of grating, $\beta$ is angle for first maxima.

If the deformation $\Delta$P is small it results in small variation of angle $\Delta\beta$, then:
$$P\Delta\beta\cos\beta+\Delta P\sin\beta=0 .$$
Ultimately:
$$\Delta \beta = -\frac{\Delta P}{P} \tan \beta,$$
which is exactly the relation I'm looking for.

What I do not understand is how the second equation is obtained from the first one. Another paper states it's through differentiation, but I cannot see how.

Can you explain to me how it was done?

Answer (score 0):

$$D(P \sin(\beta))=D(P) \sin(\beta) + P D(\sin \beta)= D(P) \sin(\beta) + P \cos(\beta) D(\beta)$$
Here $D(\cdot)$ denotes the differential operator.